# ios, KVC, why doesn't it invoke countOf<Key> when i invoke [[MyObject valueForKey:"MyArray" ] count]

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, key-value-coding, kvc

..................

```
    Environment:OSX10.8, Xcode4.5
    Reference:
    https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual
    /KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid
    /20000955-CJBBBFFA

    If the countOf method and at least one of the other two possible methods are 
    found, a collection proxy object that responds to all NSArray methods is 
    returned. Each NSArray message sent to the collection proxy object will result 
    in some combination of countOf, objectInAtIndex:, and AtIndexes: messages being 
    sent to the original receiver of valueForKey:.
```

**My steps:**

1) Create a `property` for `NSArray* arrs` in MyObject.h.

2) in MyObject.m

```
@implementation MyObject
- (void)setArrs:(NSArray*)arrs
{ _arrs=arrs; }

- (NSUInteger) countOfArrs
{ NSLog("Im here");
  return 0;}

- (id) objectInArrsAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{ NSLog(@"objectInArrs");
  return nil;
}

@end
```

3) Testing code

```
MyObject* obj=[[MyObject alloc] init];
NSArray* arr=[NSarray arrayWithObjects:@"abc",nil];
[obj setArrs:arr];
NSLog(@"%d",[[obj valueForKey:@"arrs"]count]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[obj valueForKey:@"arrs"] objectobjectAtIndex:0])
```

**My Question:**

I expect it to invoke `countOfArrs` and `objectInArrsAtIndex:` automatically, 
however, it didn't. All it does is return the normal NSArray, shows count quantity by 1 
and 'abc'.

I didn't find any helpful samples,or maybe i misunderstand what the doc says, don't I?

My tangue language is not English, hope i didn't make any ambitious issues.

Comment: unfortunately , i find sb meet the same problem with me .  http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/236041-kvc-array-proxy-objects.html           At last ,nobody answered him....   Maybe i will have same the result???

Answer (score 3):

You have implemented more functionality than what is needed.  Your `@property` declaration is adding the `-<key>` getter and `-set<Key>` accessor.  As you were able to find out, your getter (called by `valueForKey:@"arrs"`) is returning the actual NSArray assigned to the property which returns its count and object.

The guide you linked to has the reason why this didn't work in *step 1* and *step 2* of the *Default Search Pattern for valueForKey:* section.

Basically, your `-countOf<Key>` and `-objectIn<Key>AtIndex:` methods are only called when there isn't either a `-<key>`, `-get<Key>` or `-is<Key>` methods.

In order to get this to work, you need to remove the getter by removing the `@property` declaration, and then you'll need to add an instance variable to save your array.

Make this your interface and it should work

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject {
  NSArray *_arrs;
}
@end
```